# JSON Output Cant Able to Get PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to print available Market ID from this API:

https://www.coinexchange.io/api/v1/getmarketsummaries

And check if any `MarketID` are present in the following API:

https://www.coinexchange.io/api/v1/getmarkets

then print that `MarketID` data like:

```
MarketAssetCode
BaseCurrencyCode
```

What I have done so far:

```
<?php
include 'pappu.php';
$grabs = ngegrab('https://www.coinexchange.io/api/v1/getmarketsummaries');
$jsons = json_decode($grabs);

if($jsons)
    foreach ($jsons->result as $sam) { 
        $market = $sam->MarketID;
        $price = $sam->LastPrice;
        $grabsz = ngegrab('https://www.coinexchange.io/api/v1/getmarkets');
        $jsonsz = json_decode($grabsz); 
        $a = $market;

        foreach($jsonsz as $key => $element) {
            if($element->MarketID == $a) { 
                echo $element->MarketID,"<br>";
                echo $element->MarketAssetCode,"/";
                echo $element->BaseCurrencyCode,"<br>";
            } 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is that you are calling that second API every iteration which is going to kill this script. If I were you, I would put this into a class. Also, you have `if($jsons)` without `{}` wrapping the subsequent loop, which I would not advise:

```
class Markets
{
    # Allows for array conversion from api
    private $isArray;
    private $endpoint   =   'https://www.coinexchange.io/api/v1/';
    # Allow setting for array
    public  function __construct($isArray=false)
    {
        $this->isArray  =   $isArray;
    }
    # Fetch the data from the remote api
    public  function fetchApi($path)
    {
        # You may use curl or whatever...
        return file_get_contents($path);
    }
    # Fetches the api data and returns results
    public  function getRemoteData($path,$isArray=false)
    {
        $grabs  =   $this->fetchApi($path);

        if(empty($grabs))
            return ($this->isArray)? [] : (object)[];
        # Decodes as requested
        return json_decode($grabs,$isArray);
    }
    # Returns requested api url
    protected   function getDataAs($kind)
    {
        # Incase you have more api links in future, it would be good
        # to use a switch here
        switch($kind){
            case('summary'):
                $path   = $this->endpoint.'getmarketsummaries';
                break;
            case('market'):
                $path   =   $this->endpoint.'getmarkets';
        }
        # Fetches remote data as array or object
        $data   =   $this->getRemoteData($path,$this->isArray);
        # If array, send back array
        if($this->isArray)
            return (!empty($data['result']))? $data['result'] : [];
        else
            return (!empty($data->result))? $data->result : (object) [];
    }
    # Fetch the summaries
    public  function getMarketSummaries()
    {
        return $this->getDataAs('summary');
    }
    # Fetch the markets
    public  function getMarkets()
    {
        return $this->getDataAs('market');
    }
    # Create the matched array data
    public  function getMatchingMarketIds()
    {
        # Set by default as true
        $this->isArray  =   true;
        # Fetch both data sets from api
        $marketData     =   $this->getMarkets();
        $summaryData    =   $this->getMarketSummaries();
        # Set a default return
        $matched        =   [];
        if(!empty($summaryData)) {
            # Loop first
            foreach($summaryData as $sam) { 
                $market =   $sam['MarketID'];
                $price  =   $sam['LastPrice'];
                $a      =   $market;
                foreach($marketData as $key => $element) {
                    if($element['MarketID'] == $a) {
                        # Fill the array
                        $matched[]  =   [
                            'market_id' => $element['MarketID'],
                            'asset_code' => $element['MarketAssetCode'],
                            'base_currency_code' => $element['BaseCurrencyCode']
                        ];
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
        # Return the filled array (if it's filled)
        return $matched;
    }
}
```

To use:

```
# Instantiate the class (I am fetching array)
$Markets    =   new Markets(true);
# Loop through the final array and echo out the values
foreach($Markets->getMatchingMarketIds() as $row){
    echo $row['market_id'].' => '.$row['asset_code'].' => '.$row['base_currency_code'].'<br />';
}
```

Writes:

```
18 => LTC => BTC
19 => UNO => BTC
21 => DOGE => BTC
22 => KOBO => BTC
24 => DGC => BTC
25 => MEC => BTC
26 => BIGUP => BTC
31 => KORUNA => BTC
34 => XXX => BTC
35 => DBIC => BTC
38 => XBU => BTC
39 => POST => BTC
41 => IXC => BTC
43 => MXT => BTC
44 => MOJO => BTC
45 => MOIN => BTC
46 => ARG => BTC
47 => XEV => BTC
48 => GMX => BTC
49 => MAC => BTC
50 => DEM => BTC
56 => SPRTS => BTC
57 => PURA => BTC
58 => SUPER => BTC
60 => 1337 => BTC
61 => RUB => BTC
62 => SFE => BTC
63 => PIGGY => BTC
64 => GB => BTC
66 => CHILI => BTC
67 => SLR => BTC
69 => SILK2 => BTC
....etc
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$Markets' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION)  shows an error :(

Comment: Unless your PHP is not compatible with some of the script or you have pasted incorrectly, this is tested and has no syntax errors. What line?

Comment: This is meant for PHP7+. If you have a lower version than 7, you might have to change `[]` into `array()`. Other than that, this script is pretty straight forward and definitely has no syntax errors in it.

Comment: In the `getMatchingMarketIds()` method, just add it to that array assignement in the middle of the loop.

Comment: Wow Everything is perfect.... but i need to do final thing for my project , that is i need seperate Each Basecurrency code with its last price on seperate table could give me code For BTC please

Comment: `foreach($Markets->getMatchingMarketIds() as $row){$c = $row['base_currency_code'];if($c=BTC){echo $row['market_id'].' =>'.$row['asset_code'].' / '.$row['base_currency_code'].' =>'.$row['last_price'].' <br />';}
}`   is this correct??

Answer (score 0):

In your second loop you need to loop through `$jsonz->result`. Also, you need to fetch `getmarkets` outside of the loop. This data would remain same unless the data you want to fetch is different for each `marketID`.